# How do I override a scoped bean for tests?

Tags: spring, proxy, scope, javabeans

I have this bean in my Spring Java config:

```
@Bean
@Scope( proxyMode=ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS, value=SpringScopes.DESKTOP )
public BirtSession birtSession() {
    return new BirtSession();
}
```

For tests, I need a mock without a scope (there is no "Desktop" scope in the test). But when I create a configuration for my test which imports the above configuration and contains:

```
@Bean
public BirtSession birtSession() {
    return new MockSession();
}
```

I get a "Desktop" scoped mocked bean :-(

How do I make Spring "forget" the `@Scope` annotation?

PS: It works when I don't use `@Import` and use copy&paste but I don't want to do that.

Comment: What kind of test are you writing? Unit test?

Comment: What about annotating mocked `birtSession()` with `@Primary`? *Some* `DESKTOP` scope will have to be available, but autowiring will always choose you primary bean.

Comment: @JBNizet: Yes, it's a JUnit test that uses the `SpringJUnit4ClassRunner`

Comment: And do you really need a Spring container, or couldn't you simply instanciate the class under test and inject mock dependencies manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be in `ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForBeanMethod()` that uses `ScopedProxyCreator.createScopedProxy()` static method to create the scoped bean definition:

```
// replace the original bean definition with the target one, if necessary
        BeanDefinition beanDefToRegister = beanDef;
        if (proxyMode != ScopedProxyMode.NO) {
            BeanDefinitionHolder proxyDef = ScopedProxyCreator.createScopedProxy(
                    new BeanDefinitionHolder(beanDef, beanName), this.registry, proxyMode == ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS);
            beanDefToRegister = proxyDef.getBeanDefinition();
    }
```

As the `BeanDefinitionHolder` returns a `RootBeanDefinition` instead of `ConfiguratioClassBeanDenition` the scoped proxy bean definition (ie, the `ScopedProxyFactoryBean`) cannot be overriden by another Java Configuration class.

A  workaround could be declaring the scoped beans to override in a xml configuration file and importing it with `@ImportResource.`

Comment: That sounds like a bug/feature. Is that intentional or should I report it as a bug?

Comment: I think that is a bug. The ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader should not register RootBeanDefinitions as it has his own BeanDefinition class to determine whether the bean definition was created externally.

Comment: I feel that you should report this bug since you seem to know what you're talking about :-) Please add the URL to the answer or as a comment after you did.

Comment: That was fast: Fixed for 3.2.2! Thanks a lot :-)

Answer (score 0):

The problem isn't Spring keeping the annotation, the problem is that Spring first tries to parse the "productive" config and in order to do that, it checks whether the scope is available. Spring checks scopes eagerly. So it never gets to the second/overriding bean definition.

Create a dummy scope:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.ObjectFactory;

public class MockSpringScope implements org.springframework.beans.factory.config.Scope {

    private Map<String, Object> objects = new HashMap<String, Object>();

    @Override
    public Object get( String name, ObjectFactory<?> objectFactory ) {
        Object result = objects.get( name );
        if( null == result ) {
            result = objectFactory.getObject();
            objects.put( name, result );
        }
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public Object remove( String name ) {
        return objects.remove( name );
    }

    @Override
    public void registerDestructionCallback( String name, Runnable callback ) {
        // NOP
    }

    @Override
    public Object resolveContextualObject( String key ) {
        // NOP
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String getConversationId() {
        // NOP
        return null;
    }

}
```

and register that under as "Desktop" scope. That will Spring allow to successfully parse the  production config.